# Почему подсказка говорит лишь о редактировании краткого описания метки?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, описание-метки

Почему подсказка говорит лишь о редактировании краткого описания метки, хотя при переходе на страницу метки редактировать можно и полное описание?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:** это не только наша проблема: [Why tooltip does tell only about excerpt tag wiki editing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322306/260198)

Comment: Ещё и расположена криво

Comment: @Qwertiy старая тема. На MSE вроде тред где-то был про это. Они эти мелочи редко правят.

Comment: @Qwertiy [проблемы перфекционистов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288893/339911)